# Dependency of measure of angles from length of edges in a triangle with excircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

Let $P$ be the point where an excircle is tangent to the edge $AB$ of the triangle $ABC$, where $AC={1\over 3}(AB+BC)$. Prove that $\angle PCA=\angle BCP+\angle ABC$.
 ------------ 
 All I could do was play around with the angles, which let to nothing but useless tautologies. Just in case, the problem probably doesn't require mathematical analysis. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let excircle touch line $AC$ at $Q$. It is well know (and not difficult to prove-with tangent segments) that $CQ = {a+b+c\over 2}= s$ where $a,b,c$ are the sides $BC,AC,AB$ respectively. Since $4b = a+b+c = 2s$ we have $s=2b$ and so $AQ = b$. Because $AP = AQ =b$ (tangent segments from $A$ on excircle) we conclude that triangle $PAC$ is isosceles and thus the conclusion.

Comment: Maybe it's elementary, but could you give me some hints how to prove that CQ=(a+b+c)/2?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I managed to figure out the CQ=(a+b+c)/2 part myself.